# Factor game, using loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So I'm creating a program where a number is going to be factored by 2 users and the person who factor it to 1 without using the original number wins. I'm supposed to use a loop but I have no idea which is best and how to structure this to not be a convoluted mess like most of my program.

In text it should structure something like this.

a number N is input as the number to be factored. 2 Players will alternate entering a number to factor N by. The factors cannot be less than 2, and the must divide evenly into N.

- 8 is input.
- Player 1 input a factor.
- Player 1 inputs 4.
- N is now 8/4.
- Player 2 input a factor.
- Player 2 inputs 2.
- N is now 8/4/2.
- N is now 1. Player 2 won!.

The program should loop this cycle of asking for a new number from each player 1 at a time until the number is 1. I will now post my code, I am not sure how to proceed or if I'm even using the right loop, since while's are usually used for statements that are predicated on a condition being false.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

int gameN;
int factor;



    printf("What number should the game be played with?\n");
        scanf("%d", &gameN);



 while (gameN != 1)  {
    {

    printf("The current number is %d .Current Player enter a factor.\n", gameN);
        scanf("%d", &factor);

    if (gameN%factor==0){
            printf("the current number is %d . Current Player enter a factor.\n");
            scanf("%d", &factor);

    if (gameN/factor== 1){
      break;     printf("Game Over. You won!");
        }
    if (factor<2) {
            printf(" Invalid Factor. Numbers less than 2 are not allowed. The current number is %d. Current Player, enter a factor.\n", gameN);
            scanf("%d", &factor);


return 0;
```

Thanks to anyone and everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After the `scanf("%d", &factor);` there are three bad things that can happen

- the user didn't enter a number
- the number doesn't divide into `gameN`
- the factor is less than 2

In each of those cases, you want to `continue` the loop. The `continue` statement in C causes the loop to restart at the top.

As a side note, you can check the return value from `scanf` to make sure that the `scanf` worked. It will return the number of successful conversions, which in your code should be 1.

The following code shows how to use the `continue` statement to restart the loop until the user enters a valid number. It also shows how to flush the input, just in case the user enters garbage, like "fdajkl".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int gameN, factor, count;

    printf( "What number should the game be played with?\n" );
    if ( scanf( "%d", &gameN ) != 1 )
        exit(1);      // user didn't enter a valid number, so just quit

    while ( gameN != 1 )
    {
        // get a factor from the user
        printf("The current number is %d. Current Player enter a factor.\n", gameN);
        count = scanf( "%d", &factor );

        // check for all the bad things that can happen
        if (count != 1 || gameN % factor != 0 || factor < 2 )
        {
            scanf( "%*[^\n]" );     // read and discard any characters up to the newline
            getchar();              // read and discard the newline character
            printf( "That's not a valid input\n" );     // notify the user
            continue;               // go back to the top of the loop to try again
        }

        gameN /= factor;            // divide the game value by the factor

        if ( gameN == 1 )           // check for victory
        {
            printf( "Game Over. You won!\n" );
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran the code you posted to see how it worked and any input put into the program returns the "Not a valid input" printf.

Comment: @Phlash6 Did you type it in, or copy/paste? What values did you enter?